# Javascript Easing no working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, animation

The below HTML and Javascript has an easing function applied to a background. It works fine in Chrome, Safari, and even IE, but not firefox?

anyone out there know why it wont work in FF?

```js
var element = "ele";
var ease_against = true;

window.onload = function() {

  var target = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  var position = {
      x: target.x,
      y: target.y
    },

    ease = 0.2;

  document.getElementById(element).addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
    target.x = event.clientX / 5;
    target.y = event.clientY / 5;
  });

  update();

  function update() {
    var vx = ease_against ? (((target.x - target.x - target.x) - position.x) * ease) : ((target.x - position.x) * ease);
    var vy = ease_against ? (((target.y - target.y - target.y) - position.y) * ease) : ((target.y - position.y) * ease);

    position.x += vx;
    position.y += vy;

    document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundPositionY = position.y + "px";
    document.getElementById(element).style.backgroundPositionX = position.x + "px";

    requestAnimationFrame(update);
  }

};
```

```css
 html,
 body {
   margin: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   padding: 0;
 }
 #ele {
   background: url('hex.jpg') repeat;
   width: 400px;
   height: 400px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   border-top: 1px solid black;
   border-bottom: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 50%;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div id="ele">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the easing that causes your problem.

Firefox doesn't support backgroundPositionX, but it does support [background position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/background-position)

For example you can do:

```
myElement.style.backgroundPosition = position.x + "px "+position.y + "px";
```

Comment: Also `target` variable needs to be global.